# Comparing the means of two groups with different sizes

Tags: inference, mean, games

I am doing an statistical study over ultra-marathon runners (100 km distance) where I have a large number of data points (race records) corresponding to the average race speed of different runners from different countries.

I want to respond to the following question: **"what country has the fastest runners?"**

I have grouped the race records by country and calculated the arithmetic average (mean) of each of the groups. Below is an excerpt of the results table obtained:

[image: Results table excerpt]

As you can see, RUS has a mean race speed of 9.232564 km/h with a sample size of 4408 samples. And LTU has a mean race speed of 10.122746 but a smaller sample size of 365.

So which country has the fastest runners?

Comment: What's the level of data that you have access to? The time of individual runners? Are there any runners who have multiple records, e.g., when they participated in multiple races?

Comment: I have some 800K race records (one race record = one runner average speed in one race) over a long period of years. Hence many runners are likely to have several records.

Comment: Actually, the raw data files also contained the runner´s name and surname (which I discarded initially). So I could get that info back and group / aggregate by single runners.

Comment: Could you share a link to your data, preferably with individual runners identified?

Comment: @ kjetil b halvorsen
I can´t share the dataset at this point in time, but will eventually upload into Kaggle for the benefit of community.

Answer (score 2):

Direct comparisons, as your table shows, are not appropriate because the base observation is not runners but rather one runner in one race. For instance, imagine a country with poor overall running ability, but a talented runner participated in many races, leading to numerous observations. This runner's presence would introduce a severe positive bias into the mean estimates of this country.

In my opinion, there are two methods:

1. Take the average of each runner's performance and treate it as a measurement of their "real ability" of running (with measurement error, of course). Then, you can use a t-test or linear regression to compare the means of different countries with robust standard errors.
2. Use random-effects models:
   [image]

here, `i` denotes a particular runner and `j` denotes a particular race.

Comment: @ Plumber - thank you for your advice. First of all, it seems clear that my question is poorly formulated, so I need to review that In second place, I also think taking into account the unique runners is the right thing to do, so I will get back to my code and rework it. Unsure about the rest (liner regression, random-effects model) as I was indeed using some more complex ML methods additionally to the descriptive table I posted, but it will all depend on how the results look like.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of the thinking about the difference in sizes between countries is to recognize that it also means that the *precision* differs between countries. The most common way of handling this is to include all observations (i.e. data from all individual runners) and to use a model that accounts for the structure of your data (multiple observations from individual runners are not independent). Multilevel models are quite popular, though other approaches exist (i.e. sandwich estimators). So you could run a multilevel model (also called a mixed-effect model) and include runner ID as a random intercept (to account for the non-indepedence of observations). Country would be your main variable of interest. You might also want include variables for runner age and sex.

Comment: @ David B - thank you for your answer. AS indicated, I am going to rework my code to consider the multiple obr¡servations from individual runners and will decide how to continue from that point.

Comment: @David if you are thinking about going the ML route (though not sure then what question you are trying to answer), just be aware that there are also techniques in that space for handling non-independent data.

Comment: @ David B - the question I would like to answer is the same one (among others). A ML model is not just helpful as a predictive tool, but it can also be used to investigate the underlying relationships among predictors (independent) and predicted (dependent) variables. The descriptive table I shared was just an intermediate result of my analysis.  Having reworked my dataset to calculate the average race speed for each runner, it turns out that, by doing so, I wipe out relevant data (specific age and location information cannot be aggregated)... so I will no longer pursue that avenue,